# Apollo + React gives me a 400 error when performing a mutation. Possible httpLink error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, graphql

For a weird reason I am getting `400` code any time I a performing a mutation.

Here is my httpLink code

```
// ApolloProvider.js
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

which I then apply in the same file below

```
// ApolloProvider.js
export default function ApllProvider(props) {
    return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{props.children}</ApolloProvider>;
}
```

When it comes to GraphQL I am a total newbie, so I'd appreciate help. On the server everything works ok, and I am submitting the same values that I know worked on the server.

one of my mutations looks like this

```
//Login.js
const LOGIN = gql`
    mutation login($email: String!, $password: String!) {
        login(email: $email, password: $password) {
            id
            token
            firstName
            profileLink
        }
    }
`;
```

Above, to submit the values to my values to my server, I am doing

```
//Login.js
const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        },
        validationSchema,
        onSubmit: (values) => {
            formik.isSubmitting = true;
            loginUser({
                variables: { email: values.email, password: values.password },
            });
            formik.isSubmitting = false;
        },
    });

    const [loginUser, { loading, error }] = useMutation(LOGIN, {
        onError(err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
    });
```

Comment: did you check the network error log in the developer tools?

Comment: Yup. It suggests it's an error with Apollo itself `Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
    at new ApolloError (ApolloError.ts:46)`

Comment: Since next errors are connected to QueryManager.ts, and Observable.js (gotta be Apollo's internal modules).

Answer (score 0):

So this one was a simple one. I have asked for a property that was not defined on my type. Once I removed it, everything started working.

I found out what was the problem by going to the "Network" tab in Chrome, and by examining a request with the name of 'graphql'.